# How does Postman get the bearer Token

Tags: python-requests, postman

I can log in to a certain website using Postman. Doing so will set a "bearer-token" Cookie. When I export this to Python code in Postman, it generates a request that already explicitly supplies the token. However if I just post the login data with requests without giving that token, I get a 403.

How does Postman negotiate that token, can you give me a Python snippet that will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this, the login page was redirecting right after login.

So in the `requests.post/get` function, supply the `allow_redirects=True` argument and then look for a `Set-Cookie` entry in the response headers.